# concurrency of $n$ lines

Tags: matrices, geometry

there are $n>2$ lines of the kind $l_i : a_ix+b_iy+c_i=0, i= 1,2,3,\cdots n$
what is the condition for these n lines to be concurrent?

I know that for three lines concurrency the condition is given by the determinant
$\begin{vmatrix}
a_1 & b_1 & c_1  \\
a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\
a_3 & b_3 & c_3 
\end{vmatrix} = 0$

but how is it best generalized for $n$ lines? do i have to write the determinant for every three line combination or is there some compact single expression for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote $a=(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$, $b=(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n)$, $c=(c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n)$. If all lines are concurrent, then there exist $x,y$ such that 
$$
xa+yb+c=0.\tag{*}
$$ So $(*)$ implies that
$$
A=(a,b,c)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}a_1 &b_1&c_1\\ a_2&b_2&c_2 \\ \vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\a_n&b_n&c_n\end{array}\right)
$$ has non-trivial kernel since $ (x,y,1)\in \ker A$, thus $A$ is non-invertible. Then we can see from $\ker A=\ker A^TA$ that $A$ is non-invertible if and only if $A^TA$ is non-invertible where $$A^TA=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}a\cdot a&a\cdot b&a\cdot c\\b\cdot a&b\cdot b&b\cdot c \\ c\cdot a&c\cdot b&c\cdot c\end{array}\right).$$ Now, you can check  if  $\det(A^TA)=0$ or not to see if $\ell_i$'s are concurrent or not. 
**Note:** (Thanks to @Daniel Schepler) To make sure that $c$ is a linear combination of $a,b$, we should check in prior that $a,b$ are linearly independent. But this can be easily done.

Comment: I would think this would also detect the case of all $\ell_i$ being parallel, which would mean some $(x,y,0) \in \operatorname{ker}(A)$.  (Which a projective geometer would consider as being a special case of the lines being concurrent, but the OP might not be satisfied).

Comment: @DanielSchepler You're right. But I thought that the OP was assuming $a,b$ are linearly independent, at least implicitly, when he/she said that the zero determinant gives the condition. But maybe I should add that to make clear. Thank you for your comment :-)

Comment: Ah, yes, I guess the OP's condition does have the same issue.

Comment: Thanks all. Only a request. can someone give the exact expression for n=4 for my own easier understanding?

Comment: @maik, it is good to rate the answer specially if it was useful!

Comment: @Chance , how do i rate it? meanwhile can you pls write exact expression for n=4 just for my understanding.

Comment: @maik You should evaluate $$\left|\begin{array}{ccc}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2&\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i&\sum_{i=1}^na_ic_i\\\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i&\sum_{i=1}^nb_i^2&\sum_{i=1}^nb_ic_i \\ \sum_{i=1}^na_ic_i&\sum_{i=1}^nb_ic_i&\sum_{i=1}^nc_i^2\end{array}\right|$$ and see if it's zero. It is hard to write down explicit formula. By the way, what Nochance meant is probably that if you like an answer, you might upvote it by pressing the uparrow, and if you think it's the best, you should mark it as accepted by clicking the check symbol.

Comment: @song thanks i upvoted it. but because of my low reputation it is not showing. But why does your formula does not reduce to the discriminant that i posted for n=3?

Comment: @maik For $n=3$, my formula is $\det(A^TA)=\det(A^T)\det(A)=\det(A)^2$, which is the square of your formula.

Comment: @Song Thanks much for your help.